# Control de formulario no funciona correctamente

Tags: php, html, post

me encuentro realizando un control sencillo para un formulario aun mas sencillo.
Mi problema aparece cuando una estructura if no funciona según lo esperado. Siempre accede como si la condición fuese correcta. Adjunto el código por si alguien supiera como solucionarlo, muchas gracias de antemano.

```
// Nuestro array de usuarios
    $usuarios = array (
        "juan@juan.es" => "juan",
        "pedro@pedro.es" => "pedro",
        "maria@maria.es" => "maria"
    );
    // Validamos si se han enviado los datos
    if (isset( $_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["pass"])) {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $pass = $_POST["pass"];
            // Validamos si existe el email y contraseña en nuestro array
            if ( array_intersect_assoc(array($email => $pass), $usuarios) ) {
                // Si existe asignamos, redirigimos a contenido.php y finalizamos el script
                $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
                header ("Location: contenido.php");
        
            } else {
                // Si no Coinciden datos redirigimos y finalizamos el script
                header ("Location: index.php");
                $_SESSION["error"] = "Email y/o contraseña incorrectos.";
        
            }
    } else {
        // Si no hay datos redirigimos y finalizamos el script
        header ("Location: contenido.php");
        $_SESSION["error"] = "Por favor rellena los campos.";
        
    }
```

El formulario envia dos campos llamados "email" y "pass", pero aunque se presione el botón submit con ambos campos vacíos administra la respuesta entrando al primer if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<form id="miForm">
  <input type="text" name="user">
  <input type="text" name="pass">
  
  <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que los campos de un formulario se envían siempre, independientemente de si estos están vacíos o no. Entonces tus `isset()` van a provocar que siempre se entre por el `if()`.

Para hacer lo que quieres deberías añadir también la comprobación de que además de existir, tampoco estén vacíos.

```
if ((isset($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["email"])) && (isset($_POST["pass"]) && !empty($_POST["pass"]))) {
  // Lógica de si se cumple la condición
else {
  //Lógica de si no se cumple la condición
}
```